# How to update extra attributes on a join model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have three models that are related using the `has_many through` association. I decided to use this model after reading through some documentation which said: "You should use has_many :through if you need validations, callbacks, or extra attributes on the join model."

[Docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many)

user.rb

```
has_many :orders
has_many :vendors, through: :orders
```

order.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :vendor
```

vendor.rb

```
has_many :orders
has_many :users, through: :orders
```

And the schema looks like this

```
  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "vendor_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "servings", default: 1, null: false
    t.string "location"
    t.string "payment_method"
    t.boolean "paid", default: false, null: false
    t.boolean "dispatched", default: false, null: false
    t.boolean "delivered", default: false, null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "meal_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_orders_on_user_id"
    t.index ["vendor_id"], name: "index_orders_on_vendor_id"
  end
```

So now, I am looking for how to update the attributes in the order model, specifically the booleans.

What I have tried:

```
def dispatched
    v = Vendor.find_by(vendorname: params[:_vendorname])
    order= Order.where(id: params[:order_id], vendor_id: v.id)

    order.dispatched = !order.dispatched

    json: order, status: :ok 
end
```

When this didn't work I thought I'd be able to update it if I call a function from the model itself.

```
#order_controller.rb

def dispatched
    v = Vendor.find_by(vendorname: params[:_vendorname])
    order= Order.where(id: params[:order_id], vendor_id: v.id)

    order.order_dispatched!

    json: order, status: :ok 
end

#order.rb
 def order_dispatched!
    self.dispatched = !self.dispatched
    save!
end
```

The errors I am getting are `undefined_method` for `dispatched` in my first attempt, and in my second, I am getting, `undefined_method` for `order_dispatched!`.

I think maybe I do not fully understand what was being passed across in the docs. Or maybe, this is not the ideal way to handle this type of relation. I have also checked for answers, but there are a few old questions that do not have an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Order.where(id: params[:order_id], vendor_id: v.id)` returns `ActiveRecord::Relation`, not `Order` instance.

If you don't care about the performance, you can use `each` to iterate over relation.

```rb
# Before
order.order_dispatched!

#After
order.each {|o| o.order_dispatched!}
```

If you intent `Order.where(id: params[:order_id], vendor_id: v.id)` to return only one instance, you should use `find_by` instead of `where`. `find_by` returns only one record matching the given condition.

```rb
# Before
order= Order.where(id: params[:order_id], vendor_id: v.id)

#After
order= Order.find_by(id: params[:order_id], vendor_id: v.id)
```

Comment: Thanks so much... it was because of the `where`, I was trying to return only one record of the given condition.